# Exporting from Java Swing/Graphics to HTML

Tags: java, html, css, swing, fonts

I wrote small **java** Swing/canvas program where I can draw some textboxes.

Now I'd like to export those text areas to a set of **HTML** div.

What would be the best way (font-family ? font-face? css selectors ?) to obtain the same rendering as in Java ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think,  better way is rewriting program using some abstract views. And then implement this views for swing/web.